# How do I make this code work in Firefox? Currently, it only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I was making a simple todolist app and everything else works fine but my delete item code is only working in chrome and no other browser. I even tried it in latest firefox version but it just doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why.

Here's the code:

```
function removeTask(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("del")) {
    //e.target.parentElement.remove();
    let item = e.target.parentElement.childNodes[0].textContent
      .replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, " ")
      .trim();

    console.log(item);

    let url = `/items/${item}`;
    http
      .delete(url)
      .then(reloader())
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    function reloader() {
      location.reload();
    }
  }
}
```

The above code looks fine but whenever I try deleting an item, it works in chrome but is not working in firefox (latest version) and edge. I haven't checked on other browsers.

(Update: Sometimes it deletes an item but when I try deleting another item, it does not work)

Comment: "I even tried it in latest firefox version but it just doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why." What happens when you run this in Firefox? Do you get any errors in the console? If so, what are they? If not, what happens and what do you want it to do differently?

Comment: well, work the same way as it is working in chrome.. i.e. deleting a list item. It's not deleting items in firefox or edge but it's doing it in chrome

Comment: `.then(reloader())` is wrong

Comment: @epascarello I see. But, it's working in chrome. anyway, what should I change it to?

Comment: You are executing the function and setting what it returns to the then. It should be a reference.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. Even the reference doesn't fix complete problem

Answer (score 1):

```
    http
      .delete(url)
      .then(reloader())
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Here you call `reloader()` immediately and pass its return value to `.then()`. I think instead, you want to reload the page after the `http.delete()` request returns with a response. To do this, pass the function to `.then` instead of calling it first:

```
    http
      .delete(url)
      .then(reloader)
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Since `reloader()` just calls `location.reload()`, you can get rid of `reloader()` like this:

```
    http
      .delete(url)
      .then(location.reload)
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Now, it's deleting all the items. except for one

Comment: @ohnope Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.